# JSF2.2 Templating site menu with <ul>

Tags: jsf, facelets

Using JSF2.2
I have a list menu in my mainTemplate like this:

```
 <ul>
    <li class="selected">Home</li>
    <a jsf:outcome="new"><li>New</li></a>
</ul>
```

I want to put class="selected" according to my jsf current page, otherwise it puts a link.

What is the best practise?

Thanks for you attention. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

This way worked:

```
<h:panelGroup rendered="#{view.viewId == '/new.xhtml'}">
    <li class="menuSelected">New</li>
</h:panelGroup>
<h:panelGroup rendered="#{view.viewId != '/new.xhtml'}">
    <a jsf:outcome="new"><li>New</li></a>
</h:panelGroup>
```

Is this a good practise?
I don't get it to work using a bean.
(sorry for my english)